# Connect MS SQL Server with Python using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: python, odbc

I am trying to connect MS SQL SERVER with Python using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. I was using my own python code but it is not working. I used a code that I found here and I got an error message:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=PROZONEVIC-01;Database=DescartesShips;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM Test")
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print(row.Name)
cnxn.close()
```

Please, can you help me out to solve this issue?

In the Directory where is the Python code is installed the pyodbc:

```
Name: pyodbc
Version: 5.0.1
Summary: DB API module for ODBC
Home-page: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc
Author:
Author-email: Michael Kleehammer <michael@kleehammer.com>
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Comment: The port might be wrong or blocked or the connection data could be incorrect. You could try to use `pymssql` as described in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-258-python-vs-connection-refused-with-login/ba-p/3703542 to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Follow [this 3 easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16) steps.

Comment: who is _"Mr. Gord Thopmson"_ ?

Comment: The person who solve similar issues in Stack Overflow is Mr.  Gord Thompson.